# Creating a list of instances in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was under the impression this would populate my list with instances (or references to) of my second class but when run I just get a list filled with `none`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DataStructure : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int size;
    public List<DataEntry> dataList = new List<DataEntry>();

    void Start()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
        {
            DataEntry newEntry = new DataEntry();
            dataList.Add(newEntry);
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DataEntry : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string text;
    public int number;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `new` to instantiate `MonoBehaviour`s.  Easiest solution in this case without further information is to make `DataEntry` no longer a `MonoBehaviour`: `public class DataEntry { ... }`. If you do need it to be a `MonoBehaviour` for the purposes of attaching to GameObjects, you should instead use `AddComponent`.

Comment: what is the value of size? none

Comment: @LeandroBardelli Not necessarily. `size` could have a nonzero value assigned in the unity inspector.